# Android Firebase: No matching client found for the package

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I had borrowed an android project from one of my friends and after importing, I got an error that the `The application was configured for some other audience - appId doesn't match the one in google-services.json`. After that, I knew I had to change the package name of java files and reconnect firebase so, I did. I keep getting an error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.***.***.chitchat'
```

I have the same package name in AndroidManifest.xml, build.gradle and google-services.json. Strange is that everyone got their problem solved after making the required changes. Mine still throws an error. Why is that?

Comment: This issue is the same on iOS builds, and the solution is the same as Doug's solution below, just in the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file, also in the app folder like the json. So maybe this question could lose the `Android` prefix since it's cross-platform?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package names of your Java code actually has nothing to do with that error.  It's the application id of your entire app that you need to look at (in your build.gradle).

The google-services plugin looks at your application id and tries to match it against a package name that it fines in your google-services.json file.  If there is no match, it will give you that error.  To resolve this, either change your application id in build.gradle to match the package name that was set up for your app in the Firebase console, or create a new app in the console with a package name that matches your application id.

If you borrowed a project from a friend, I suspect that you also got a hold of their google-services.json, which you typically don't share or check into source control, unless everyone has full access to the same project.  If you're working in your own project, you'll need to set that up in the console and generate a new google-services.json to match your app.

Comment: I just read that the applicationId in build.gradle is independent of the application package name so, I changed that. I regenerated a google-services.json but, it still says no matching client even when I can clearly see that JSON tree has values corresponding to applicationId in build.gradle

Comment: Post the contents of your files?

Comment: Hey, I found the issue. There were 2 google-services.json. One was under the `debug` build variant which strangely wasn't getting updated through Firebase tool I was using. The one which Firebase tool did update was in app/google-services.json and the other was in app/src/debug/google-services.json. But, as I said, we still need to change the applicationId to match the one in google-services.json. No need to change the package name.

Comment: The app folder is the default location, yeah. Gradle will tell you which one it's using (in the case of multiple flavors) in the build output.

Comment: Thanks Doug, this solution is spot-on. Also, for iOS builds, there's a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file in the same location (app root) with the same app id which needs to match. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem here is that you have multiple build types in your gradle.

try and add a suffix according to the build type in the json file.

This might solve the error.